# Move duplicated folder name up one level

Tags: files, mv

I have a folder structure:

`/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/several-files-and-folders-here`

I would like it to instead be:

`/mnt/data/mydata/several-files-and-folders-here`

I tried `mv` but it complains the folder isn't empty, and I wasn't able to find a feasible fast solution that I understood, I'm still new to learning Linux. How would one fix this correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moving every file in the subdirectory into the parent is one way, but if there are a *huge* number of entries in `/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/`, and that's the only entry in `/mnt/data/mydata`, you might consider this sequence of 3 metadata operations that doesn't change the contents of the big directory, just moves it to a different place in the filesystem.  And removes 1 entry from a small directory then unlinks it.

Thus it won't affect the ctime of any of the files in the subdirectory or even have to list the contents of that big directory.

```
 mv  /mnt/data/mydata            /mnt/data/mydata.old   # rename parent
 mv  /mnt/data/mydata.old/mydata /mnt/data/mydata   # subdir -> sibling of parent
 rmdir  /mnt/data/mydata.old     # fails if not empty
```

The directory inode that was originally `/mnt/data/mydata/mydata` is now `/mnt/data/mydata`, and its contents haven't changed.  If it contained millions of files, that's faster and takes less i/o.  But more typing because `mv` won't invent a temporary name for you.

If the original `/mnt/data/mydata` wasn't empty, you can still do this but instead of `rmdir`, `mv /mnt/data/mydata.old/*  /mnt/data/mydata/`.  If it had a couple entries vs. a couple million for the child directory, that's saving some I/O.

You do need write access to `/mnt/data`, which the other way doesn't need.  But this doesn't need write access to `/mnt/data/mydata/mydata`.

Script this however you like, and/or `cd` and use relative paths.  Pick any temporary name you want, like `foo` or `tmp`, or `xyz123`.  (If other users can write `/mnt/data`, and you're scripting it, check on what `mv` will do if they create a file with the same random name you pick; or use `mktemp -p /mnt/data/` to get a temp dir there to move the child `mydata` into while you unlink `/mnt/data/mydata`.)

It has the downside that there is a moment between operations when no `/mnt/data/mydata` exists at all.  Unless there's a shell wrapper for the [`renameat2` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) with `RENAME_EXCHANGE` to atomically exchange two paths. (Linux kernel 3.15, glibc 2.28, so it's been around for a while, but `rename(1)` and `mv(1)` don't have options to use it.)

If you're running a server, this might matter to you, otherwise you likely don't care.

---

Interactively, you might also use `imv /mnt/data/mydata` to interactively edit the path with readline line-editing (the same as bash uses for command-line editing.)

Answer (score 5):

#### How it's done

The way it's done is you'd need to move the contents of:

```
/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/
```

to

```
/mnt/data/mydata/
```

first ... And afterwords you can just delete the now empty directory, if you like, with e.g.:

```
rmdir -v /mnt/data/mydata/mydata/
```

`rmdir` is safe ... It will only delete the directory if it's empty and error otherwise.

#### How to move

**Either** (*with no dry-run*) simply:

```bash
echo mv -nv -- /mnt/data/mydata/mydata/* /mnt/data/mydata/
```

**Notice**: `echo` before `mv` is just a safe guard from accidental copy/paste ... You need to remove it for the command to work ... No dry-run here, so **be careful**.

**Or** (*with a dry-run*) utilizing `bash`'s [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) around either of the repeated directory names (*e.g. either the leading one with: `"${parameter/mydata\//}"` or the trailing one with:`"${parameter%mydata/*}${parameter##*/}"`*) and a `for` loop  ... A one-liner would be something as simple as:

```bash
for f in /mnt/data/mydata/mydata/*; do echo mv -nv -- "${f}" "${f%mydata/*}${f##*/}"; done
```

**Notice**: `echo` is inserted before `mv` for a safe dry-run ... Remove `echo` only when satisfied with the output and run the command again to do the actual moving.

**Demonstration**:

```bash
$ tree /mnt
/mnt
└── data
    └── mydata
        └── mydata
            ├── dir1
            │   ├── file1
            │   ├── file2
            │   └── file3
            ├── dir2
            │   ├── file1
            │   ├── file2
            │   └── file3
            ├── dir3
            ├── file1
            ├── file2
            └── file3

6 directories, 9 files
$ for f in /mnt/data/mydata/mydata/*; do mv -nv -- "${f}" "${f%mydata/*}${f##*/}"; done
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/dir1' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/dir1'
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/dir2' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/dir2'
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/dir3' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/dir3'
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/file1' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/file1'
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/file2' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/file2'
renamed '/mnt/data/mydata/mydata/file3' -> '/mnt/data/mydata/file3'
$ tree /mnt
/mnt
└── data
    └── mydata
        ├── dir1
        │   ├── file1
        │   ├── file2
        │   └── file3
        ├── dir2
        │   ├── file1
        │   ├── file2
        │   └── file3
        ├── dir3
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        ├── file3
        └── mydata

6 directories, 9 files
```